# Is it possible to insert code block from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

For example given something like this

```
const stuff = [{"a": "b"}]
const inhtml = document.querySelector(".exists")
const pre = document.createElement("pre")
pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stuff))
inhtml.appendChild(pre)
```

I want it to output the array [{"a": "b"}] in a code block dynamically

Except it just outputs [Object object ...]

Comment: one problem is that code never uses the variable `stuff`

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify(obj) to help convert an object into a string.

Comment: oh that works! Is there a way to format it properly as well @PotatoParser

Comment: Yes! You can do JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t') which will automatically tab key/values on the inside!

Comment: That's EXACTLY what i wanted thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to display the text:

```js
const stuff = [{"a": "b"}];
const inhtml = document.querySelector("div#main");
const pre = document.createElement("pre");
const code = document.createElement("code");

code.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(stuff, null, '\t');
code.style.backgroundColor = '#ebccca';

pre.appendChild(code);

inhtml.appendChild(pre);
```

```html
<p>Code goes below here</p>

<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, that worked. Is there a way to format it also

Comment: You can format the output using CSS.

Comment: @shah I've updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, so there is no way to color code basic javascript color in the code block without css?

Comment: You can use javascript to set the style attributes. I've changed the answer to show how.